# Cannot create instance of 'ProductListingUserControl' defined in assembly ProductListing

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

Hi I am getting following error:

> Cannot create instance of 'ProductListingUserControl' defined in assembly 'ProductListing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' in markup file 'ProductListing;component/views/productlistingcshostedcontrol.xaml' Line 22 Position 10.

I have a user control which I am using in another class.In another class I have defined  an event ProductSelectionChangedEvent which is giving me above error whenever I am creating the instance of my User control.

I am creating following event for my user control:

```
Window w = Window.GetWindow(productServiceFunction);
w.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(ProductListingUserControl_LocationChanged);
this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(ProductListingUserControl_SizeChanged);
```

Comment: “Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.” That sounds like there is another exception that's actually causing this. Is what you posted the whole exception?

Comment: yes.Thats the whole exception